# Bivariate expression in mod q with same roots as expression in mod p

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Suppose you have an expression of $x, y$:
$$ y + ax + b = 0 \mod q $$
with roots $x_0, y_0 \in (0, q)$.

How can one construct a similar expression but in mod p:
$$ y + A(a, b, q)\,x + B(a, b, q) = 0 \mod p(a, b, q) $$
with $p > q$, such that it has the same roots $x_0, y_0$.

Comment: “Same roots”: what does this mean? In my outlook, $\Bbb Z/(p)$ has nothing whatever to do with $\Bbb Z/(q)$, supposing that $p$ and $q$ are primes. Or did you mean “$\!\bmod(p,a,q)$” for something modulo $pq$?

Comment: $p$ doesn't have to be prime. And not all roots need to be the same, just the ones in the range $(0, q)$.

Comment: For simultaneous congruences modulo two numbers that are relatively prime, you use Chinese Remainder Theorem. Have you tried that? And what does “mod $p(a,b,q)$” mean?